# remove left sidebar (Joomla)?

Tags: joomla, user-interface

I'm a new CiviCRM user, trying to find my way through the extensive number of options. What a powerful solution!!

Working on a small screen, I'd prefer to be a able to hide the sidebar with the 'recent items' and 'new individual' fields to save some space on the screen.
Ideally find some switch that can toggle the sidebar off and on.

Is that possible?

Stefan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Glad you're enjoying CiviCRM so far.

The Joomla layout for CiviCRM currently has that sidebar hard-coded in. However, you could hide it with 1 line of css and reclaim that space (or with maybe 3 lines of css you could conditionally hide it depending on the width of the screen). I then recommend you install the [Recent Items Menu](https://civicrm.org/extensions/recent-items-menu) extension which will still allow you to navigate to recent items without the sidebar.

Comment: Thank you!
I will try and figure out what CSS code I'd need.
If you have any tip, that would be welcome!
And I'll give that extension a try.

Comment: It's pretty simple, you just right-click on the sidebar and choose "inspect" from the drop-down; that will show you the css selector to use.

Comment: Thank you, Ill try that out!