# Adding "Phone" Option to the "New Individual" Section on CiviCRM Homepage

Tags: profile, joomla, phone, individual

I am looking to add a "Phone" option within the "New Individual" section on the CiviCRM homepage. However, I am unable to locate where this customization can be made. Can you please provide guidance on this matter?

[image]

I access the "Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Profiles" section. Here, under the "User-defined Profiles" section, I added the "Contacts - Phone - Primary" option to both the "Supporter Profile" and "Your Registration Info" profiles. However, there was no change in the field on the main page. An example screenshot is provided below.
[image]

Subsequently, I also added the "Contacts - Phone - Primary" option to the "New Individual" profile under the "Reserved Profiles" section, but there was still no change in the field on the main page. An example screenshot is provided below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Edited: I thought this was a profile, but it is not. It has the same name as a profile and the same fields, but it is actually a template, see comments below.

Comment: NOTE - the New Individual is listed on the RESERVED PROFILES tab.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your response. I had tried your suggestion before. However, that solution didn't work. To provide a clearer understanding of the situation, I've included the steps I took in response to your recommendation. Could you please review it again?

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work. Turns out it isn't actually a profile, it is hard-coded here: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/master/templates/CRM/Block/Add.tpl
I always assumed that it was the profile of the same name, but it isn't. Have edited my answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: As far as changing it, you'd have to either change it in core to use the profile instead or do an extension to modify the form.

Comment: Thank you again for your interest. In this case, it seems that making changes to the field for a standard user is not possible. So, is it possible to completely remove this field?

Comment: To get rid of the New Individual block entirely? You can remove the CiviCRM Quick Add block in your CMS. Personally, I prefer to hide that whole sidebar so there is more space for tables in the main block.

Comment: It's also a very good idea to completely remove the sidebar. How do you do this.

Comment: Not sure how it works on Joomla, but on Drupal you just remove all the blocks from that region. But you might also want to consider installing a different theme, many get rid of all those blocks.

Comment: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/45261/remove-left-sidebar-joomla Unfortunately there is no Theme in Joomla to change the appearance of CiviCRM. :)